# Get visible size of control in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a control that doesn't displayed fully (by decreasing of window size).
But ActualWidth and RenderSize/DesiredSize of this control still show the total size of it.
I wrote the next code, but it ignores the scrollbar width of window and looks ugly.
Maybe there is a way to get a visible size of control with more elegant manner?

```
    private static double GetVisibleWidth(UIElement element, FrameworkElement container)
    {
        var visibleBounds =
            element.TransformToAncestor(container)
                .TransformBounds(new Rect(new Point(0, 0), element.RenderSize));

        double visibleWidth = element.RenderSize.Width;
        if (container != null)
        {
            visibleWidth = Math.Min(container.ActualWidth - visibleBounds.X, visibleWidth);
        }

        return visibleWidth;
    }
```

[image: What size i am speaking about]

Answer (score 2):

[`LayoutInformation.GetLayoutClip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.layoutinformation.getlayoutclip(v=vs.110).aspx) could be what you need.

> Returns a Geometry that represents the visible region of an element.

But note that if the `element.IsArrangeValid && element.IsMeasureValid == false`, this will return `null`. Here's a method you could use:

```
private Size GetVisibleSize(FrameworkElement element)
{
    Rect? bounds = LayoutInformation.GetLayoutClip(element)?.Bounds;
    if (bounds == null)
    {
        return new Size(element.ActualWidth, element.ActualHeight);
    }
    return new Size(bounds.Value.Width, bounds.Value.Height);
}
```

This won't work when your element is inside a scrollviewer though, since it is not technically clipped.

Comment: LayoutInformation.GetLayoutClip returns null for element and its visual parents. I suppose IsMeasureValis is false in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Let's select the element and go up the visual tree while finding the intersections with the element and it's parents.

**Here...**

```
private Rect GetVisibleBounds(UIElement element)
{
    var currentBounds = new Rect(element.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0)), element.RenderSize);
    var container = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element) as FrameworkElement;
    while (container is not null)
    {
        var containerBounds = new Rect(container.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0)), container.RenderSize);
        currentBounds.Intersect(containerBounds);
        container = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(container) as FrameworkElement;
    }

    return currentBounds;
}
```

Comment: Works great, except sometimes you don't have an intersection with a parent. I'm not sure why though. If you skip the intersection assigning when it returns true for IsEmpty it still works. Also this answer does not take dpi scaling into account. You have to multiply the scaling with the RenderSize. The position is already in screen coordinates. It goes without saying that the return value is always in screen coordinates.