# WPF: Calculating the size of a Grid Column

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a grid that contains three columns.

```
<Grid Background="AliceBlue">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="8*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" Name="ManualControlsSplit" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

The first column contains a Grid and a chart.

The second column contains a GridSplitter.

The third column contains a StackPanel which contains a number of TextBlocks, Buttons and Grids containing TextBlocks and Buttons. Text size is dynamic and based on translation resources.

I need to calculate the minimum width that the contents of the third column would ideally like to be able to be drawn into so that the contents are not clipped.

My knowledge of WPF is limited to what I can google so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I know that I can set the control to auto size to the width I wish to calculate using the following: "parentColumn.Width = GridLength.Auto;". However this is not what I want.

Comment: I don't get it. Can't you set the third column to Width = "Auto" ?

Comment: I don't want to change the width I want to calculate the ideal width as I need to use that value in some other logic.

Comment: You can't calculate (as far as i know) the width of something that is not even rendered, unless you gave to each control inside the third column a fixed width. Best you can do is to add an event handler for the Grid.Loaded and then check the Actual Width. Again if you set the third column to Auto you will have the minimum width required

Comment: Further googling hints a measuring, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745058(v=vs.90).aspx#LayoutSystem_Measure_Arrange, but its not at all clear how this can be used.

Comment: The following is probably away of achieving this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36926571/get-visible-size-of-control-in-wpf. I would need to see if this occurs too late for me to use the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My WPF XAML setup is as follows (bits removed to keep this simple):

```
<UserControl ....>
  <Grid Background="AliceBlue" Name="TopGrid">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="12*" Name="Graph" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5" Name="GridSplitter" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" Name="ManualControlsSplit" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Column="0" Background="AliceBlue"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <!-- A Graph and simple controls -->
    </Grid>

    <!--  GRID SPLITTER  -->
    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Width="5"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="Splitter" />
    <Label Grid.Column="1" Content="⁞" Foreground="White" 
          Background="DarkGray"
          VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="26" FontWeight="Bold" 
          IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
    <!-- end GRID SPLITTER -->

    <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Margin="5"
          Name="TemperatureControls">
    <!-- Load of Controls -->
    </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

To calculate the desired width I use the following code:

```
// get my UserControl object
var manualControlView = userControl as HeatingController.Views.ManualControlView;

// Query the current width of THIRD column
double actualWidth = manualControlView.ManualControlsSplit.ActualWidth;

// Set up a BIG size (this has to be bigger size than the contents of the
// THIRD column would ever need)
Size size = new Size(400, manualControlView.TopGrid.ActualHeight);

// Ask WPF layout to calculate the Desired size.
manualControlView.TemperatureControls.Measure(size);

double width = manualControlView.TemperatureControls.DesiredSize.Width;
if (actualWidth <= width)
{
   // Too small - do something
}
else
{
   // big enough - do something else.
}
```

The variable 'width' now contains the value I wanted to calculate.

Answer (score 0):

With layout in WPF, you can allow one if not more of the `Grid.Columns` to be `<ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>`. This essentially tells WPF to allow as much space as the contained controls want. The use of `Auto` cascades too, so in `StackPanel` you refer to, you can make that controls width `Auto` as well, likewise with the items it contains; if the stack panel merely contains a `TextBlock` (via some template or whatever), then you can also set this width to `Auto` and the width with set itself according to the contained text.

```
<Grid Background="AliceBlue">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    ...
    <StackPanel Grid.Column=2
                Width="Auto">  
        <TextBlock Width="Auto" 
                   Text="This is TextBlock"/> 
        ...
    </StackPanel>   
...
</Grid>
```

In this case the `Text` of the `TextBlock` sets the width of the `StackPanel`, which in turn sets the width of the 3rd grid column.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I actually need the calculated width for the items drawn. As I said the second column is a GridSplitter. I can query how wide each of the columns are. However I need to know what the 'ideal' drawn size of the contents of the third column is. I'm not interested in auto sizing to fit the contents. I actually want to know what the calculated auto size is without drawing.

Comment: The "ideal draw size" will be handled for you by WPF using Auto and adopting a shared size scope. It will automatically size to the largest text block. I don't understand why this is not a solution for you...

Comment: Yes I know that WPF will handle the ideal size calculations for me if I set the width to auto and I know it will draw the contents for me. BUT that is not what I asked. I want to know what that ideal size is as I need it for something else. I don't want WPF to perform the drawing and auto sizing.